# FutureTask, unsafe action

Tags: java, futuretask

I'm getting this warning while compling my code (with -Xlint options):

```
receptor.java:286: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to 
FutureTask(java.util.concurrent.Callable<V>) as a member 
of the raw type java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
```

The line that generates the warning:

```
FutureTask task = new FutureTask (new Return(address, lock));
```

And the Return class implements Callable:

```
public class Return implements Callable <String> {
```

How can I fix the warning?

Comment: `FutureTask<String> task = new FutureTask<String> (new Return(address, lock)); `

Comment: Why do you compiling the code with -xlint?

Comment: Because I got the advice that I'm using unsafe operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`FutureTask` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), this class is a generic class as well. This means you'll need

```
FutureTask<String> task = new FutureTask<String>(new Return(address, lock));
```